# Serial Communication with Arduino and MATLAB - debugging issue

Tags: matlab, arduino-uno

I have written the following MATLAB code that takes each element of the array "sendData" and sends it to an Arduino Uno. The Arduino then uses this data to determine what configuration the motors must run in using an if/ ifelse loop.

When I step into the while loop line by line the motors sometimes will turn. When they do not I try to execute the fprintf statement in the command window and that tends to work.

If anyone has any insight into why this code does not execute properly when I run and/or step into it, but will work fine when I execute the fprintf statement in the command window, I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
delete(instrfindall);
clear all;
clc

% assign hardware to variable a
a=serial('com3');
% create incriment variable
incr = 1;
% create sendData string array
sentData = ['1','2','3','4','0'];
% loop through the 4 possible motor set ups

while incr<5
     % open link to arduino
     fopen(a);
     % send string to arduino

     % open link to arduino
     fopen(a);
     % send string to arduino
     % string will be an index from the sentData array
     fprintf(a,sentData(incr));
     pause(2);
     % close the file
     fclose(a);

     % inciment
     incr =incr+1;
end
% tunr off all motors by sending '0' to Arduino
incr=5;
fopen(a);
% send string to arduino
% close the link
fclose(a);
```